# Disable Resharper intellisense for single assembly

Tags: c#, resharper, intellisense

I'm working on a project that references a dll that has been obfuscated. The dll has many namespaces and classes that are single letters.

My issue is that many times while typing, Resharper will suggest classes from this assembly, e.g. if I am typing 'Report' it will suggest 'r.e.p' from this other assembly.

Is there a way I can get Resharper to ignore this one particular assembly for intellisense options?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible now - there is the same [feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-40982).

Comment: Seems to be possible now. However, I was unable to get it to work. See [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-40982)

Answer (score 0):

If your source code is located under a single parent directory, [Resharper allows you to exclude it](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Code_Inspection__Settings.html):

Goto Resharper -> Options, Settings, then press the 'advanced button'
There you can enter the directory and/or files to exclude from the solution wide analysis.

Comment: This doesn't seem to exclude files from Intellisense?

Answer (score -2):

Go to Resharper > Options > Intellisense. Just look at it if you can find what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, are you saying that the option exists there, or that I should just check the options in case I had not already? I have looked through the Intellisense options and I can't see anything that looks like it would allow me to exclude certain assemblies or namespaces

Comment: Sorry for a broad answer. I don't think there's a single assembly exclusion, disabling options there would affect everything else.